# Variants of icon sizes not showing up in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to include variations of an icon's size in my Android Studio res/drawable folder. I downloaded the icon that I wanted from [material.io/icons](https://material.io/icons/) and placed the different variants of the icon into my drawable folder.

Here is the drawable folder: [image]

However, in Android Studo, there are  no drawables found. [image]

I am having trouble understand why this is happening because I have already created another app with images of differing sizes. That app [here](https://github.com/chasen-bettinger/MiwokTranslatingApp/tree/master/app/src/main/res).

Comment: did you create the drawable folders manually or through icon insert into the IDE? have you tried invalidating caches and restart IDE?

Comment: Can you navigate to the actual project folder and see what is in there?

Comment: @marcosE. I created the drawable folder manually. Invalidating caches and restarting IDE resulted in this: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Chasen\AndroidStudioProjects\android-client\app\src\main\res\drawable\drawable-xxxhdpi: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Comment: @AlécioCarvalho Yes I can. All of my images are there.

Comment: certainly your files aren't properly named..

they must respect the naming conventions there, as  the message says: ending with .xml or .png AND no dashes..like:

ic-bla.png  ---> ic_bla.png

Comment: for a random test, try the following:

File --> New --> Image Asset 

you will be given a 'image asset generator' by generating it will populate those folders eliminating other possible causes for your problem.

Comment: Manually copy one by one and paste the images into drawable folder inside the IDE, when the IDE ask you to select the folder to paste add -hdpi / - xxhdpi into the path so the IDE will create the folders for you, after that you should be able to add manually icons into the folders.(Be aware of MAYUS, unsupported characters or blank space on the name of your files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a drawable folder and placing each separate image into the folder, copy and paste each variant into the res directory.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Project pane (on left hand side), if you have selected 'Android' menu then you can't see the different drawable folders as it merges all the folders in one. If you change the menu to 'Packages' then you would be able to see all the folders you have created manually.

Comment: They're there, but I can't use them. Android Studio throws an error when I try to use the image as a src.

Comment: Make sure that all the same images (different size) files have same names. And when referring them in code u dont have to specify their sizes. U just have to specify the name of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

Create All the drawable folders inside the `res` folder outside the sudio and just refresh the project inside the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you have included the icons in the drawable folders according to resolutions  , so if you want to see if the icons are present in the drawable folders . You need to change the menu from "Android" to "Packages" , you should see different drawable folders and icons in the respective folders .